# How Can I Add A Custom Shortcut To My List Of Applications Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, shortcuts

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04...wow a lot has changed since my days of version 10 lol. Anyways, I installed Eclipse and the Android Dev suite, however, in order to launch the Eclipse program, I have to navigate out to it's location under my 'home' directory and manually double-click on the Eclipse executable, it does not show up when I search the "applications" list.

I have tried and have so far been unsuccessful at adding a shortcut, pointing to the Eclipse .exe, to the applications list. Since I don't have access, only root does, I used the "cp" command to copy the shortcut into the usr/share/applications folder, however it still does not show up when I search for it under "applications".

I know I could try pinning it to the tool bar on the side, but I do not want to do that. There has to be a way to get applications to show up when searching the "applications" list.

Anyone out there know how? So far my attempts to find the answer via Google have proved futile.

Comment: Did you mean custom launcher?